# can not see video on the website

Tags: ros, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to follow the video on navigation tutorials to set up rviz for the Navigation Stack,but I can not see the video,it is blank where the video should play.I  Click the right mouse button，it shows "Movie not loaded".I have installed flash before. what's the problem ?Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/157101/can-not-see-video-on-the-website/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no trouble viewing this video. This is probably something wrong with your flash player or something else on your system.

Can you view other videos on YouTube? Perhaps your country of residence blocks access to youtube?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-27**:
thank you,I have no access to youtube!